# How to automatically change functions in a M-file that have been removed/changed between two releases of Matlab?

Tags: matlab, automation, migration

I’m seeking help with automation of a process. In short, I have a list of Matlab codes/applications (30 of them in total) written in the 2011a and 2018b. This means over 100 000 files with .m or .p extensions, many of them include functions that have changed/removed. I would like to automate the migration process as describe below:

```
1.  Make a list of all matlab functions that have changed/removed between the 2011a release and the 2018b release (Has been done already)
2.  Get all the m-files and p-files that exist in a specific directory (store them in a variable), (Has been done already)
3.  Automatically open each file (defined as above) then:
    a.  Scan each line of code and
    b.  If any of the function listed above appear in the code, then:
        I.  If it’s simply changed name (i.e same syntax and same number of arguments) then:
            •   automatically replace it everywhere in the code
            •   Save and close the file
        II. If the syntax of the function has changed for example the function takes one more or one less argument, then do the following:
            •   Show where the function appears in the code
            •   Let the user manually change it once (dialogue box)
            •   Then automatically apply the new syntax everywhere else in the code to replace the old syntax
            •   Save the file and close it 
        III.    Otherwise: save and close the file
```

Comment: You cannot change P-files. If you have the original M-files they were derived from, modify the M-file and re-build the P-file. Otherwise, you either contact the author or rewrite them from scratch. P-files are encrypted and designed to hide implementation.

Comment: Are there really functions in 2011a that were not deprecated then and don’t exist any more? That’s hard to believe! Usually deprecated functions live for a long time.

Comment: For 3.b.II, *'automatically apply the new syntax'*, how does the automation process know how to do this? Can the user write a regex, for example, to change the old to the new syntax? Then your process is quite easy to automate. Or is the automation tool supposed to somehow learn what the transformation is? Then it's rather hard.